# Is there a better way to solve this - Programming Principles & Practices Using C++: Ch. 4 - Drill?

Tags: c++

I solved this problem -

> Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time around the
>   loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a
>   terminating '|' is entered.

using 2 approaches -

1) By reading inputs as **int**s and comparing the first one with `'|'` like this -

```
int i1, i2;
while (cin >> i1){
    if (i1 == '|')
        break;
    cin >> i2;
    cout << endl << i1 << " " << i2 << endl;
}
```

But with this, I can't input 124 as `'|' == 124`.

2) By reading inputs as **string**s and converting them to **int**s using a function (I created) like this -

```
// main function
    string s1, s2;
    int i1, i2;
    while (cin >> s1){
        if (s1 == "|"){
            cout << "\nBreaking the loop\n";
            break;
        }
        cin >> s2;
        i1 = strtoint(s1);
        i2 = strtoint(s2);
        cout << endl << i1 << " " << i2 << endl;
    }

// string to int
int strtoint(string s)
{
    int i, j, val = 0, temp = 0;
    for (i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        temp = s[i] - '0';
        for (j = 1; j < (s.size() - i); ++j)
            temp *= 10;
        val += temp;
    }
    return val;
}
```

But now the question further says to read doubles, and using this 2nd approach means expanding `strtoint()` to read `double` values (which is annoying).

All I want to know is that is there any better way to solve this problem as 1st method has a bug and 2nd one requires more code. Or should I just go with the 2nd one?

Comment: Feed the string to a stringsteram (include sstream) then pop the stream to an int or double or float or anything! It will be parsed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the second method, but implement the conversion like this to be more convenient:

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
T from_string (std::string const & s)
{
    std::stringstream ss (s);
    T ret;
    ss >> ret;
    return ret;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
int a = from_string<int> (s1);
double d = from_string<double> (s2);
```

This is not exactly the best, but it does work (hopefully)!

Of course, you can always use the `std::stoi()`, `std::stod()`, etc. functions from the `<string>` header. In fact, I suggest these over the above method.